# File is created on local, but does not exist on Heroku deployment - Java Api

Tags: java, api, rest, heroku, jersey

I have an API that creates a temporary file when calling one of the resources, at the end of the method this file is deleted.

**Example**:
Retrieves all products
`http://localhost:8080/api/v2/products/allproducts`

**API flow**:

1. Gets all products;
2. Creates new temp_file;
3. Writes to new temp_file;
4. Stores information in file and returns it;
5. Deletes temp_file;

This API has been fully tested locally and it's working! The file is created, read and then deleted, all goes well.

When I deploy the API to Heroku, I get a 500 Internal Server Error "java.io.FileNotFoundException" (No such file or directory) - the catch block of the call

(Read more bellow)

```
dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=500 bytes=871 protocol=https 2023-03-20T22:04:36.792371+00:00 app[web.1]: Unable to create tempfile 2023-03-20T22:04:36.792387+00:00 app[web.1]: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ./src/main/java/org/test/resources/temp_allproducts.json (No such file or directory) 2023-03-20T22:04:36.792523+00:00 app[web.1]:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method) 2023-03-20T22:04:36.792524+00:00 app[web.1]:   at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270) 2023-03-20T22:04:36.792533+00:00 app[web.1]:    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213) 2023-03-20T22:04:36.792534+00:00 app[web.1]:  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162) (...)
```

I wonder if the file path is different in Heroku, or if there's just something I'm not doing within the exemplified flow.

I'll leave you with a sample of how I create this tempFile.

```
private static File makeTempFile(String data, String fileName) {
        File file = new File(BASE_PATH + "temp_" + fileName+ ".json");
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
            writer.write(formatJson(data));
            System.out.println(BASE_PATH + "temp_" + fileName + ".json" + " created");
            return file;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to create tempfile");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

So the problem was that I was defining absolute paths. Heroku's environment is working with a different context, so I have to explicitly define the directory path where the files will be created.

Inspired on @Meruem suggestion for a solution I came up with this fix and it worked 100%

```
private static File makeTempFile(String data, String fileName) {
        String tempDir = HEROKU_RESOURCES_BASE_PATH;
        if (tempDir == null) {
            System.err.println(tempDir + " environment variable not set");
            return null;
        }

        File dir = new File(tempDir);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            if (!dir.mkdirs()) {
                System.err.println("Failed to create temp directory: " + dir.getAbsolutePath());
                return null;
            }
        }

        File file = new File(dir, fileName + ".json");
        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file)) {
            writer.write(formatJson(data));
            System.out.println(file.getAbsolutePath() + " created");
            return file;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Failed to write to temp file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```